# Wants to display the cursor busy for more time

Tags: kendo-ui, cursor

I have a web page with 9 drop downs and a kendo grid.I am making the ajax call for all drop downs.When I load the page the values in the drop downs gets loaded vary slow with some default values.During the loading period of drop downs I want to show the cursor for kendo grid to be wait.Cursor as a wait is coming but disappearing very soon .I want to show the cursor to be wait until all the drop down gets loaded so that user cannot make any selection in any of the drop down.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 function ShowLoadingCursor() {
        $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
    }
    function HideLoadingCursor() {
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowLoadingCursor();
    });

    $(window).load(function () {
        HideLoadingCursor();
    });
```

I am using MVC approach.I have uncountable number of  web pages.It is impossible to implement the code in all pages.So I am writing the above code in Layout.cshtml page.I can't hard code any drop down id or grid id.Only thing is in all pages i want to display the cursor to be wait until all drop down gets loaded.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using these DropDowns in multiple places, I would create a Partial View. This way you can implement my answer in that partial view, and then render that view whenever you want to

Answer (score 0):

When the page is loaded change the cursor's style to wait.

Tap into the DataBound event of the Last DropDownList that is loaded. This will fire when the ddl is finished loading it's data.

```
//kendo dropdowncode
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound").

function onDataBound()
{
 //remove wait cursor and replace with default mouse cursor
}
```

EDIT:

You can place the JS functions that will handle the change of the cursor in the _Layout.cshtml page, any view that uses that shared layout will have access to those functions.

As far as your Kendo Grids are concerned, you will have to register the event manually for each grid. Your JS functions will be in shared layout so you don't have to worry about adding them again. One other suggestion would be to not to use AJAX to fill the dropdowns, and "pre populate" them before the view renders. I'm not sure of any other way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks C Sharper for your valuable time and suggestion.Actually I have 20 pages like that and in future I will be having 35 pages like that.So If I use your code I need to implement that in each and every page .I want to do something globally.That's why I wrote the code in layout.cshtml.I am looking for an solution which I can implement in layout.cshtml page and call that function in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your central problem is you a not working with the display model as designed.  The idea behind doing AJAX/MVC/JSON web technology, is that each part of the page makes its own call to the server, and individually, the parts report ready when they get done rendering their responses.  That way, if part of the page takes a long time to get, the user can interact with the rest of the page in the intervening time.  The paradigm you are using was designed to do the opposite of what you are trying to do.  My advice to you is to thoroughly examine this requirement.  You should find a way to not do this.